# Wait for network on systemd.run kernel parameter (like require/wants in systemd units)

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, manjaro

I'm using [the `systemd.run` kernel parameter](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/kernel-command-line.html#systemd.run=) to apply some auto-configuration tasks on the first boot of Manjaro ARM minimal like setting the hostname, adding a default user, ... and I'd like to install packages using `pacman`. Everything works except installing `pacman` packages. For example, I'm trying to update all packages and install vim:

```
pacman -Syu --noconfirm
pacman -S --noconfirm vim
```

This throws several errors for each mirror, for example

```
+ pacman -Syu --noconfirm
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core downloading...
 extra downloading...
 community downloading...
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from manjaro.mirrors.lavatech.top : Could not resolve host: manjaro.mirrors.lavatech.top
warning: too many errors from manjaro.mirrors.lavatech.top, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'extra.db' from manjaro.mirrors.lavatech.top : Could not resolve host: manjaro.mirrors.lavatech.top
error: failed retrieving file 'community.db' from manjaro.mirrors.lavatech.top : Could not resolve host: manjaro.mirrors.lavatech.top
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from ftp.nluug.nl : Could not resolve host: ftp.nluug.nl
```

I tried to ping my local server as well as a internet domain, e.g.

```
+ ping -c1 192.168.0.19
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

So it seems that the network connection is not established yet when the script runs. I tried [`systemd.wants`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/kernel-command-line.html#systemd.mask=) but it still doesn't work, the network is not avaliable. Also tried different units as `systemd.wants` in `cmdline.txt`:

```
systemd.wants=systemd-networkd.service
systemd.wants=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
systemd.wants=network-online.target
systemd.wants=dhcpcd.service
```

The systemd directives in `/boot/cmdline.txt`:

```
systemd.run=/boot/my_init_wrapper.sh systemd.run_success_action=reboot systemd.unit=kernel-command-line.target systemd.wants=systemd-networkd.service
```

Since the [`systemd-run-generator`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run-generator.html#) only mention three options (`run`, `run_success_action` and `run_failture_action`) I think that I misunderstood the first doc and it seems not possible to set dependencies for `systemd.run.generator`. I'm wondering about this, since systemd units itself can specify different types of dependencies. Is there any other way how we can speficy them in the kernels `cmdline.txt`?

I'm trying this on a Raspberry Pi 4. But since this question is only about systemd, imho it doesn't matter if it runs on a pi or any other machine with systemd. So I posted it here as general linux question instead of the RPI platform.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case you are better off to not go via `systemd.run` but to make it a normal service and make use of `ConditionFirstBoot=yes` - at least for the `pacman` part.

According to the [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#ConditionFirstBoot=), such units better also refer to `first-boot-complete.target`

```
[Unit]
Description="Update packages & install vim"
ConditionFirstBoot=yes
Wants=first-boot-complete.target
Before=first-boot-complete.target
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
#optional ping test
#ExecCondition=/usr/bin/ping -c 2 -w 2 manjaro.org
#not running arch - adapt pacman path if need be:
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pacman -Syu --noconfirm
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pacman -S --noconfirm vim

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The ping test might be interesting due to the [uncertainty of what "network is online" means](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/).

---

Citation from the manual for the first boot condition:

> ConditionFirstBoot=
>
> Takes a boolean argument. This condition may be used to conditionalize units on whether the system is booting up for the first time. This roughly means that `/etc/` is unpopulated (for details, see "First Boot Semantics" in `machine-id(5)`). This may be used to populate `/etc/` on the first boot after factory reset, or when a new system instance boots up for the first time.
>
> For robustness, units with `ConditionFirstBoot=yes` should order themselves before `first-boot-complete.target` and pull in this passive target with `Wants=`. This ensures that in a case of an aborted first boot, these units will be re-run during the next system startup.
>
> If the `systemd.condition-first-boot=` option is specified on the kernel command line (taking a boolean), it will override the result of this condition check, taking precedence over `/etc/machine-id` existence checks.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but how do I create the unit? Is it possible to use `systemd.run` to create this unit? Is it then started after `systemd.run` or do I need an additional reboot?

Comment: @Lion I wouldn't see why not but cannot test it. An additional reboot would be contradicting regarding the first-boot requirement.

Comment: That's the issue I see but it's already struggeling with the network part. I tried `network-online.target`, `nss-lookup.target` and `network.target network-online.target` but still getting the same _Could not resolve host_ errors from pacman. When running the command like `/usr/bin/pacman -S --noconfirm vim` manually in a terminal, the package got successfully installed without any error.

Comment: After trying many things, also scripts who are waiting for an IP with `hostnamectl -I`, it seems that we don't have any network in scripts started by `systemd.run`. The only way I could work around this is specifying `Restart=on-failure` and `RestartSec=5`. Instead of `ConditionFirstBoot=yes` I use `ConditionPathExists=!/boot/my_init_done`, so it's started _after_ the first boot (where `systemd.run` is started). The file `/boot/my_init_done` got removed after my packages were installed. Creates some errors until the DNS works, but I couldn't find a better solution.